# Can I write a cast operator in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jsweet

I've used JSWEET to transpile a large Java project. It has converted types like Enumeration<Object> directly to Enumeration<any> in TypeScript.

In the Java world it was possible to assign an array Object[] to an Enumeration<Object>.

In Typescript I get: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Enumeration<any>'

Is there a way to extend Enumeration<Object> OR any[] in such a way that TypeScript will allow this assignment to occur?

Comment: Java doesn't allow you to assign an `Object[]` to an `Enumeration<Object>` but never the less I assume you don't need the answer about Java so removing the tag.

Comment: Could you tell more about what you mean by "In the Java world it was possible to assign an array Object[] to an Enumeration<Object>"? If you actually try to write `Enumeration<Object> e = anArray;` in Java, you get a type mismatch error. So what is your context here?

Comment: I'm generating Typescript from Java, but I made a mistake in some of my additional parts which led to my presumption that you could assign those two types in Java. Doesn't look like C++/C# style cast operators can be written in Typescript though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast in two different ways:

```
var doSomething = function <T>(a: Enumeration<T>) { };
var x: Object[] = [];

// cast using "<>""
doSomething(<Enumeration<Object>>x);

// cast using "as"
doSomething(x as Enumeration<Object>);
```

But your `Enumeration` should probably extend `Array`:

```
interface Enumeration<T> extends Array<T> {
    // ...
}
```

## Update

```
class Enumeration<T> extends Array<T> {
    private _cursor: number;
    public constructor(...elements: T[]) {
        super(...elements);
        this._cursor = 0;
    }
    public nextElement() {
        this._cursor = this._cursor + 1;
        return this.values[this._cursor];
    };
    public hasMoreElements() {
        return this._cursor < this.length - 1;
    }
    public static fromArray<T>(arr: T[]) {
        return new Enumeration<T>(...arr);
    }
}

interface User {
    name: string;
}

let a: Array<User> = [{ name: "user1" }, { name: "user2" }];
let b: Enumeration<User> = new Enumeration({ name: "user1" }, { name: "user2" });

a = b; // OK: Enumeration<User> is assignable to Array<User>
b = a; // Error: Array<User> is not assignable to Enumeration<User>
```

Maybe you can add a method `fromArray` to the enumeration class:

```
var doSomething = function <T>(a: Enumeration<T>) { };
doSomething(Enumeration.fromArray<User>(a));
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of extending Array<T>. Wouldn't that allow assignment from Enumeration to Array in one direction not the other?

Comment: assignment only works in one direction but maybe you can add a method `fromArray` to your `Enumeration` class? See my update.

Comment: Extending the intrinsic objects appears to be as close as Typescript gets to what I'm looking for.